# How to set PTR Record for mail server (Amazon + google domain)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, mail-server

I have setup amazon EC2 server and Setup SES to send emails. I have purchased domain from google domains. Now i want to setup PTR record.

Can any one let me know where and how i can setup my PTR record? Whether it would be in Route 53 of amazon or it is in DNS configuration of the google domains and what value i will add there?

Comment: It is possible to configure a `PTR` record for a server in EC2, but if you are using SES, you do not need a `PTR`.  Please explain why you believe that one is needed.

Comment: #Micheal.. Emails are going to junk folder for hotmail. I have read some blogs which is stating that it could be of PTR record issue. That's why i am trying to configure it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of PTR records for mail servers are specifically for when you are hosting your own servers and want other mail servers to know that your mail server is the authorative mail server for your domain.

Unfortunately there isn't much weight given to PTR records by spam filters any more (because it is a trivial matter for a spammer to create a PTR record)

Amazon SES uses [DKIM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim-dns-records.html) to validate the identity of the domain it is sending from.

Once that is set, if you are still getting mail marked as spam then it comes down to an issue of the quality of the messages and whether your users have interacted with your messages previously.

Comment: Hmm, I already uses DKIM to validate the identity of the domain.